DC-DC (Buck converter) shuts down when LDO enabled (intermittent)
I've encountered a problem on SOME of the boards in the pre-production batch where the boards' main 5V rail generated by a DC-DC buck converter shuts down at the moment when one of the loads generated by an LDO is turned on.

The power distribution circuit is common in my other designs and has proven to be reliable, however, it is the first time when the buck and LDO are placed closer on the board, so the power rail traces are shorter.



The LDO only powers a WIFI module similar to ESP32 Mini, nothing else.
C1060402 is placed right at the output pin of the LDO, followed by C102 0603 and C105 0603. 2-layer PCB.
the trace between the LDO and WiFi module is <10mm
I measured the inrush current of 2.7A peak when LDO gets enabled, which is well below the peak current of MP2315

After reading TI's [AN-1482 LDO Regulator Stability Using Ceramic Output
Capacitors], I tried to desolder C106, but eventually found that removing C102 or C105 solves the issues (only 4.7uF bulk). C106 doesn't affect the issue.
MP2315+BCT2057EUK33 are capable of withstanding higher inrush current when the loads with much higher bulk capacitance are switched, not sure why it happens in this instance.
Part of layout.

I do not understand the root cause of such behavior, anybody can share their insights on how to get to the bottom of this.
Thank you.

What does the buck input waveform look like?

Can you post the layout?   I wonder if this could potentially be a an EMI  coupling problem?

@EricEvertonI have added a snippet in the description

Any scope captures on output? It's difficult to know with current information that you have provided. But if this occurs during LDO enable, there's two possibilities: EMI or a shorted LDO. You can measure LDO output continuity to ground.

@Colin This is an intermittent issue on some of the boards. No shorts in the output, all the power rail dips are within the acceptable range.

Taking a wild guess here since I'm the type of person who needs the board in front of me to understand the issue... But my guess is that when mentioned that you removed some capacitors and that it worked, an assumption of why that could have worked is because you're decreasing your ESR on the output of the LDO and thereby, increasing stability for internal feedback loop inside of your LDO. Something you could consider is utilizing a bode plotter and seeing the phase and gain margins to see where your LDO would go haywire.

I tried to connect U5 and U9 ground by a wire to see if there's a return path issue. But see now improvement.

@MMG - Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "áccepting" your choice of the best answer i.e. click the "tick mark" next to an answer to make it green - either your answer (which can be áccepted after 2024-05-29 @ 22.16 UTC i.e. 48 hrs after the question was asked) or another answer (which can be accepted any time) if one is written & if you consider it the best one.

Root Cause - Only a single 0.3mm via connects U5 ground pin the the ground plane on the bottom layer, the current carrying capacity is just not enough. Certainly, the ground pin needs a better ground stitching. Installing a botch wire to the closest pad+via resolved the issue.
Interesting observation - in some instances, replacing U5 solved the problem, but apparently it was due to decreased solder joint resistance due to a larger contact area after manual resoldering. At some point I thought, we got a bad batch of U5.
